# Legends overlap plotly graph

Tags: plotly, angular5

In my case, legends data are dynamic and I want to set the position of legends on top center of graph. It can be a single or more than 100 legends as well. So, I can not fix the height of graph container. Legends overlap graph if legends are 40 or more.

Is there any way to fix this issue by auto height like if legends are more then graph should increase it height to adjust accordingly?

[Here's an inline link for code]

Comment: Code to reproduce issue: https://codepen.io/vijaythapak/pen/BYwErw

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you may set `yanchor: "bottom"` instead of `yanchor: "middle"` in the `legend` block, which will cause the plot to adjust its height automatically.

Comment: Thanks @nicolaskruchten for you quick response. It works only for when I have set height 600. What if I have more Legends like 80 and I do not set height(1000). It overlaps graph again. Any generic solution where I need not to set height of graph and It's adjust it's height accordingly.

Comment: The legend can push down the top margin of the chart *area* but cannot affect the height of the chart container itself unfortunately.

Comment: @VijayThapak Bro, I am also facing the same issue, can you suggest how you have fixed.

Comment: Bro, I have moved my legends position to right instead of top.